# Change default color of button in Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, button, next.js

I am having a problem changing default color of buttons in Next.JS Web Application.
It's button text color is grey when I see it in google chrome in Desktop, but looks blue when I open it using my Mobile chrome browser.
I want to make the button text color as grey in both of them.
The way of customizing the button text color using styles is not the way I want, because I want to make the default color of all button texts (my customized button, or button inside node modules) to be same. Please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have your code but this might work then let me know

```css
button {color:green !important;}
```

```html
<button>Change my color</button>
```

Comment: Yeah that works.
But that made button:disabled color as green, but it needs to be some different.
I am not sure how the original css default color works, but I tried that and it worked.

button {
color: green;
&:disabled {
color: grey;
}
}

Thanks Crystal